# Access repeated value in a string using perl

Tags: perl

I'm very beginner in Perl, and I faced the following issue,

I have a text file, contains values of different string,e.g.
*ExAC_SAS=1;**word=0.01**;ExAC_EAS=0;ExAC_FIN=1;ExAC_NFE=0;**word=0.0136**;*

And I want to add both values in an array.

I have tried to loop through the files and added the values to an array, and it works well but it only add the first value not the second.

```
    while ($line=<IN>)
    { chop $line; @result=();
    @arr=split('\t', $line);

    if ($arr[7]=~/word=(.*?);/) {push (@result,$1);}
```

I want my array @result to have the following values:
`1,0.01,0,1,0,0.136`

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this cli:

```
 perl -lne 'push @a,/=(.*?)\;/g;END{print "@a"}' your_file
```

Test below:

```
$ cat temp
C_SAS=1;word=0.01;ExAC_EAS=0;ExAC_FIN=1;ExAC_NFE=0;word=0.0136;
$ perl -lne 'push @a,/=(.*?)\;/g;END{print "@a"}' temp
1 0.01 0 1 0 0.0136
$
```